# jQuery Not Working in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eclipse

Still a bit new with jQuery so I may be making a basic error.
I just completed the jQuery introductory course and now am trying to do some of my own basic work, but have hit a slight road block. 
Essentially it seems the jQuery file script.js isn't getting called properly. 
When I ran it inserting it into stackoverflow it seems to work fine. However,
when I pull the html file in the browser it only displays the html elements in the file and not any of the jQuery code.

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("body").append("<p>I\'m a paragraph!</p>");
   /* write 'Hello World! to the first div' */
   $("#first").append('<h1> Hello World!</h1>');

   //a clickable 'Hello World!' example
   $("#link").click(function() {
    $('#greeting').append("<h1>Hello Again!</h1>");
   });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World - jQuery Style</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="first"></div>
 <div id="second">
  <a href="#" id="link">Click Me!</a> <br /> <span id="greeting"></span>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: @D4V1D there are no errors of any kind in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your current javascript file after you get the jquery.min.js

If you look in your console ( right click and inspect ) You will notice that it cannot understand $ jquery sign.

Solution should be just swap these two lines in your html :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: if yes then please mark my solution as an accepted answer. There is tick mark on the left. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the order of the  tags for script.js and jquery.min.js so that jquery is initialised first