# Hide two radio buttons out of four

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have small program that contains 4 radio buttons which are divided separately to 2 radio button for "FromLocal" and 2 for " FromServer".
So I'm trying to hide radio buttons on conditions:
If any radio button from "FromLocal" is selected, then it will hide the "FromServer" radio button for that I have written a program **HTML:**

```
<div id ="radiobutton1" >
  <strong>FromLocal:</strong>
  <input type="radio" name="target" value= "BrowserDownload">BrowseLocal
  <input type="radio" name="target" value="dumpToS3"  > S3Remote 

<br/>
</div>
<!-- <div> -->
<div id="textboxes" style="display: none" >
  <strong>ACCESS_KEY_ID: </strong>
  <input class="box"  type="text" / > <br/>
  <strong>ACCESS_SECRET_KEY: </strong>
  <input  class="box" type="text" /> <br/>
  <strong>MAIL: </strong>
  <input  class="box" type="text"  /> <br/>
</div>

  <strong>FromServer:</strong>
  <input type="radio" name="server" value="serverDownload" id ="radiobutton2" >ServerBrowseLocal
  <input type="radio" name="server" value="serverdumpToS3"id ="radiobutton2" > ServerS3Remote
```

**Js:**

```
$("input[name='target']").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == "dumpToS3")
       $('#textboxes').show('slow');
    else
        $('#textboxes').hide();
});
$(function() {
if ($('#radiobutton2').is(':checked')) 
    $('#radiobutton1').hide();
 else if ($('#radiobutton1').is(':checked')) 
    $('#radiobutton2').hide();
});
```

**This is the site link where I'm trying to run it:**

http://jsfiddle.net/y92kuzcL/29/

I have tried but don't know why its not working maybe the code I've written is not correct.
Please help me how to get it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hides the other 2 radio buttons(local/server) on click of other 2 radio buttons(server/local)

```js
$("#radiobutton1 > input").change(function(){$("#server").hide()})
$("#server > input").change(function(){$("#radiobutton1").hide()})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="radiobutton1" >
  <strong>FromLocal:</strong>
  <input type="radio" name="target" value= "BrowserDownload">BrowseLocal
  <input type="radio" name="target" value="dumpToS3"  > S3Remote 

<br/>
</div>
<!-- <div> -->
<div id="textboxes" style="display: none" >
  <strong>ACCESS_KEY_ID: </strong>
  <input class="box"  type="text" / > <br/>
  <strong>ACCESS_SECRET_KEY: </strong>
  <input  class="box" type="text" /> <br/>
  <strong>MAIL: </strong>
  <input  class="box" type="text"  /> <br/>
</div>
<div id="server">
  <strong>FromServer:</strong>
  <input type="radio" name="server" value="serverDownload" id ="radiobutton2" >ServerBrowseLocal
  <input type="radio" name="server" value="serverdumpToS3"id ="radiobutton2" > ServerS3Remote
  </div>
```

Comment: thnx a lot its working for me but unable to accept the answer don't know why

Comment: your code is running only fiddle when applying on Eclipse i don't why its not working i have applied it in my main html file http://jsfiddle.net/zc1pua69/3/ its working fine online but when i'm writing same file its not working Please help if possible

Comment: Consider this link if it helps     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801653/jquery-not-working-in-eclipse

Comment: Can you please also tell the exact error you are getting in the console

Comment: Mandwara there is no error i'm getting only thing is i'm running whole programs at once by using <script>js</script> in this i'm writing my javascript code but the its hiding thing is not working

Comment: There must be some other error in the  code which might be interfering with this one.

Comment: Program is running as always but the hiding radio button is not working even  when i copy pasted the same code in fiddle but not in my IDE